# Creating switch statements in Mapbox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm trying to create a switch statement for the `leftCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation` in `Mapbox iOS`. I've tried various ways including creating a `CustomPointAnnotation` class and a reuse identifier, but couldn't get it to work either.

In the end, I created what you see below. It's not the kind of code I would like to use. Any input would be much appreciated.

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, leftCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? { 

  if (annotation.subtitle! == "Name") { 
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName")!)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    return imageView
  }

  if (annotation.subtitle! == "Name2"){
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName2")!)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    return imageView
  }

  if (annotation.subtitle! == "Name3"){
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName3")!)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    return imageView
  }
  return nil
}
```

Annotations

```
for location in locations {let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = location.title
        annotation.subtitle = location.subtitle

        annotations.append(annotation)
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching based on the subtitle is not a good approach.  You're basing your logic on the UI layer, which is backwards.  Aside from the confusing architecture, it will break when you localise your application.

You should subclass `MGLPointAnnotation` and add a property to indicate what type of point it is.  I'd do something like:

```
enum PointType {
    case FirstPointType
    case SecondPointType
    case ThirdPointType

    var imageName: String {
        get {
            /*
             You can implement whatever logic you'd like here, but if
             you follow the pattern of "FirstPointType.png" for your
             images, defaulting to the case name is probably easiest.
             */
            return String(self)
        }
    }

    var image: UIImage? {
        get {
            return UIImage(named: imageName())
        }
    }

}

class CustomAnnotation: MGLAnnotation {
    var pointType: PointType
}

func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, leftCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? { 

    guard let annotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation else { return nil }

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: annotation.pointType.image)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    return imageView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, leftCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {

    var imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = ... // Set the frame for the imageView.

    // Optional binding to either create non-optional value subtitle or escape the statement.
    if let subtitle = annotation.subtitle {
        // subtitle is a non-optional value, cases must also be non-optional.
        switch subtitle {
        case "Name": imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
        case "Name2": imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName2")
        case "Name3": imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName3")
        default: return nil
        }

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        return imageView
    }

    return nil
}
```

Another approach you can take if you don't want to use optional binding:

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, leftCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {

    var imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = ... // Set the frame for the imageView.

    // annotation.subtitle is an optional value, cases must also be optional.
    switch annotation.subtitle {
    case nil: return nil
    case "Name"?: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    case "Name2"?: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName2")
    case "Name3"?: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName3")
    default: return nil
    }

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    return imageView
}
```

Comment: After implementing the approach above, I keep receiving the following error: "Expression pattern of type ‘String' cannot match values of type ‘String?" I've edit my original question to include annotation information for populating the map in Mapbox.

Comment: If you're getting that error you haven't implemented it properly. The error you're getting happens because a `switch` statement can't compare optional values to non-optional values. In the above answer the value of `annotation.subtitle` is cast into a non-optional value or nil through optional binding with the `if let` statement.